# External laptop-format device for desktop

Tags: display, keyboard

i am looking for one specific device in the laptop format. This thing must not have an hdd, ram, cpu etc like in standard laptops. It's like a external wired keyboard, but with a screen and in a laptop format. Or it's like a monitor with keyboard in a laptop format. Hope you will understand what i mean.

I have a desktop with internet and i want to control my desktop with something like rackmount monitor keyboard. Not wireless, remotely at a distance of several meters lying on the couch.

Comment: I have an old laptop without any internals. $999!

Comment: You want a LCD monitor connected to a keyboard?  If this product exists the monitor would not exactly be very mobile.  You would be better off with a mobile wireless keyboard ( bluetooth ) with a seperate small lcd monitor ( again would not be portable since were not talkng battery powered ).

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding, but I think I know what you're getting at. You're looking for just a keyboard and display that are attached to eachother and hinging, like in a laptop. Like a rack console. In fact, is a rack console exactly what you're looking for, or are you looking for a smaller/portable version?

Comment: For reference, this is a rack console: http://www.ipctechnology.com/products/rack-console/smk-920/smk920s17-overview.htm

Belkin and CMS are probably the biggest manufacturers. Most units have a KVM built in (in Belkin's case, a networked KVM).

Comment: yes. i mean something like rackmount monitor keyboard, but for desktop, if there is any difference

Comment: So do you expect this thing to be wireless? Like, you plug your computer into a Station and this station projects a wireless signal to your "laptop console". The laptop console will then act as the KVM for the desktop?

Comment: Try to edit your question in more of a understandable way so that we can try and figure out what you're looking for. A scenario without asking should i buy this or this would be preferred. Something like, hey. I have a desktop that is in a room without internet connection. I cannot access this computer at all times as the room is locked and will need to remotely access it using something like a rack mount. What's the best way to accomplish this.. That would be more of a real question and not a shopping question.

Comment: question was edited

Comment: I really think an old laptop/netbook is the cheapest way to go.

Comment: @Nifle i think about it, but i think sometimes i will need power of my pc.

Comment: Yea, that's why you use the old computer to remote to your server (rdp or vnc).

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're asking for

[image]

but I think you mean.

[image]

Comment: Leapfrog makes some gooduns' of these. Kinda 'spensive, but colorful and fun.

Comment: Lol, yes, on second pic is what i need)))

Comment: Links and specs?  Especially for the second one ;)