# Laptop Interface for Desktop Computer

Tags: keyboard, display, desktop-computer

I usually buy gaming laptops.  The main reasons are as follows:

1. I like that I can use them in my lap on a couch without any furniture or mounting.
2. The monitor is easily adjusted, either with the hinge or my moving my legs
3. The keyboard is attached and doesn't move without requiring any furniture
4. I am not being intrusive with my gaming while being in the shared living area of my residence.

I don't really care about the portability, though I do use it as my primary portable computer because I think it is silly to have two laptops when you only really need one portable computer.

I have decided that I should buy a desktop computer, as they are cheaper, more durable, upgradable, and more powerful.  And I only really game from one location.  **But I can't find a way to use a desktop from a couch without mounting something to a wall or buying new furniture.**

Basically, I want something that looks like a laptop, but is simply a monitor and keyboard (and perhaps a mouse) that plug in to a desktop nearby.

I haven't seen this available for purchase, so **I would like to know of this is something I could reasonably build, or ask someone to build, out of an old dead laptop.**

If I am to build it, I intend to convert the existing components for desktop use.  However, there is one major component I do not know what to do with.

How can I identify a compatible keyboard controller for a laptop keyboard?  Do such controllers exist?  I know there are monitor controllers for laptop monitors that accept HDMI inputs, as well as a fairly reliable method for acquiring them, but I can't find a reliable way to identify a compatible laptop keyboard controller.  If I could convert the laptop keyboard in to a USB keyboard, then I could reasonably build this device myself.

This question has been asked before, but it has been a few years and maybe there are newer solutions.  The device in the second link is about 3 times more expensive than it should be, with a 1366 x 768 screen and costing around $600, plus I am not sure if it operates without significant latency.

Related questions:

1. [How can I use a desktop like a laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/464030/how-can-i-use-a-desktop-like-a-laptop)
2. [External laptop-format device for desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/374597/external-laptop-format-device-for-desktop)

EDIT:  Software solutions have been suggested, so I feel I should note that I dual boot my machines with Linux and Windows, so software solutions are not so good because they will not work in GRUB or BIOS.  Plus, I would like to keep the latency as low as possible, so a hardware solution is best.

"On Hold" appeal:  Though I did mention that I could not purchase the interface, that was not the focus of the question.  **I asked whether this was a reasonable thing to build myself, not to purchase, as well as advice on how to convert an existing laptop.**  As a guide to what I don't know, I also ask for more specific advice for existing components I already own that I do not know how to convert.  Therefore, this is not a question about "where can I purchase" or "what can I buy to do this", but rather "How do I build this" and "Is there a way to determine what I need."  I am NOT asking for purchasing advice as a primary question, as it is my belief that the thing I am looking for does not exist for sale.

If the item in question is the laptop keyboard controller, the paragraph is about determining which one I need, not where I can get one.  Of course, the end goal for me is to acquire one, but I didn't ask where I could get one, I asked how I could determine what kind I need.  To reduce the appearance that I am asking for specific items to purchase, I reworded that section.

It is possible this is in the wrong stack exchange, so if you believe this is off topic, could you direct me to a stack exchange where it is on topic? Because this is where I was directed for hardware questions.

Comment: The options are still basically the same, only now there are some choices of netbooks that are smaller and lighter than a typical laptop.  Requests for product recommendations are off-topic, and general fishing for ideas is often considered too broad, so this is likely to get some push-back (notice that one of your linked questions is closed).

Comment: I did not know that stackexchange existed.  I looked on meta for where to post hardware questions, and it said here.

Comment: I don't think I am casting too wide of a net.  I have a few layers, each a bit more specific, any of which could be an answer.  And the lowest level which stops me from building it myself right now is the inability to get a keyboard controller.  Usually, when I just keep it simple without explaining my motivations, I get asked a lot why I want the answer rather than answers themselves.  Though I do understand that this might be the wrong stackexchange for it, but I didn't know of a better one when I wrote it.

Comment: @Zarquan , you mentioned only gaming from one place.  If that place is a desk, then it's fine to have a normal desktop there, and have a separate laptop.  It's normal to have multiple PCs.

Comment: @Christopher Hostage But it is not a desk, it is a couch.  I say this in point 1 at the top.

Comment: @Zarquan, I didn't want to assume that the couch was where you were gaming, as it didn't mention it specifically.  I know that if I used a gaming laptop on my lap, it would burn my legs.

Comment: And, now you know. I've seen hackers who are comfortable with soldering VGA-cable into a laptop screen, and cable from the laptop keyboard (no controller required) out by USB to a desktop or server. but I am short on details. There's also software solutions: https://www.spacedesk.net https://www.realvnc.com/en/ and http://avatron.com/applications/air-display/ among others, but they are not gamer-fast.

Comment: @K7AAY For most uses, I would be happy with a software solution.  But for this, I want a hardware solution for two reasons.  The latency on software solutions tend to be extremely annoying to me.  I also dual boot my machines with Linux and Windows, so any software solution would have to apply at BIOS or GRUB, and I don't think that exists (except capture cards, but those have latency again).  I will alter my question to reflect that I dual boot.  I guess I could be willing to solder a solution, but I really would rather not.

Comment: I would also like to say thank you everyone for commenting with your suggestions so quickly.

Comment: RealVNC works in both Linux (DEB and RPM) and Windows. Not gamer-fast, but there's binaries for both OS.

Comment: @K7AAY True, but when I boot my computer, how would I choose between Linux and Windows without a dedicated monitor and keyboard for that purpose?  I guess I could have the computer itself on a desk or table and turn it on, set it up, then go to my laptop.  But then there is the not being gamer fast issue.  Plus, I'm not a big fan of my computer's basic usability being dependent on a router.

Comment: @Christopher Hostage I somehow missed your comment.  I usually put it on a book or something when I game.  But I wouldn't need to if I had this device.

Comment: **Could you search [Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) and possibly ask there? Your question will be on-topic there.**

Comment: @miroxlav Thank you, that is very helpful.  I have had two questions that were put on hold for this reason and this is the first time anyone has linked me to that stack exchange.  I actually think I have decided not to use the laptop keyboard and instead just use a USB keyboard and mount it in the chassis.

Comment: Depending on what games you play, Steam has a device that streams the games from one PC to a TV set top style box.  It seems they call it "in home streaming" https://www.howtogeek.com/189601/how-to-use-steam-in-home-streaming/